# Low German translation question

Tags: translation, english-to-german, low-german

I am working on a family lineage-related art project and am looking for someone who can translate into Low German/Low Saxon the phrase "A pleasure to be seen." I am open to various interpretations (with explanations please), especially of the word "pleasure," as I know direct translations are not always possible. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moin, moin!*

I only have a very superficial knowledge of Plattdeutsch, learning to read and speak only a bit of it while I traveled in North Germany several times.

But I do have a couple of Plattdeutsch-Hochdeutsch dictionaries in which the English noun "pleasure" is given in Plattdeutsch as either "*Pläseer*" (cognate of English "Pleasure" ) or "*Vergnögen*" (cf. German "Vergnügen"-->"joy, pleasure").

I believe that the English to Plattdeutsch translation of the English phrase "to be seen" would be something like "*to't ansehn*" (from Hochdeutsch: "zu ansehen").

Putting everything together, for your English phrase "A pleasure to be seen" I come up with a Plattdeutsch translation of "*Een Pläseer to't ansehn*."

Grammatically incorrect, I suppose.  But, oh well, at least it's a start for you.

Comment: Putting this question "on hold" utterly and completely defeats the purpose of StackExchange and the German Language Q&A forum.  Like it or not, Plattdeutsch is in fact a part of the German language.  Were Plattdeutsch not a unique element of the German language and culture, then Radio Bremen would't spend the hours that it does in broadcasting the news in Plattdeutsch, and cultivating and encouraging the use of that German language dialect among its North German listeners.  Please rethink your "HOLD" order for the question; my answer clearly meets your stated forum criteria.